# HTML5 audio not supporting android Webview

Tags: android, html

Hi I am using android WebView for playing HTML5 video and audio files. When I am working file from local server "http://myip/kids_sample/Alphabets/A/A_main.html" the file is working good. But when I am trying to play file from my assets folder "file:///android_asset/kids_data/Alphabets/A/A_main.html" it's not working, please help me come out from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html parse library to get tag & parameters and made your own player on background

1- inject javascript code with function returning doc html
2- wait to onfinish loading
3- call the function from vebview, to get html code,( next javascript inject, aka function(); )
4- get the function result
5- parse html tags, and get attributes
6- made action from tag with parameters